# Strange lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm going though some c# source code and came across this piece of code, which I do not understand.

```
someVariable += (s,_) => this.Close();
```

What is happening here?

Comment: the underscore is a valid variable name, it should signify most likely a variable that is not used.

Comment: `_` is a valid variable name.  For example: `var _ = 2;`

Comment: Are you asking about the underscores, or are you asking about the `+=`? (It's an event subscription).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already stated, `s` and `_` are variables which are used as parameter for the anonymous method.
For your understanding, this

```
someVariable += (s,_) => this.Close();
```

is pretty much the same as

```
someVariable += AnonymousMethod;

private void AnonymousMethod(object s, object _) 
{
   this.Close();
}
```

The types of the parameter for the method are automatically inferred by the definition of the event `someVariable`. I used `object` since we don't know how the event is defined.

Answer (score 6):

The underscore is a valid variable name. It should signify most likely a variable that is not used.

I use it like this to express that the variables are not used further:

```
someVariable += (_,__) => this.Close();
```

Comment: I dont really get it, is there a reference for this so I could learn?

I normally only use lambda for lists like the functions (select, where, groupby and so on..)

Comment: Is the undercore the source for the confusion or is it the general expression of the form: `someVariable += (s,e) => this.Close();` ?

Comment: I do hope you don't ever have too many unused parameters... `_, __, ___, ____` :-)

Answer (score 2):

`s` and `_` only the parameters which are not used in this lambda function.